# spring injection bean which inherits from interface

Tags: java, spring

I have config with some @Bean annotations and it works. 
But if I change the bean to inherit from interface it isn't work. Do I need special annotations o something like?

config class snippet without imports

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("io.github.aaa4")
//@ComponentScan({ "io.github.aaa4.dao", "io.github.aaa4.entity","io.github.aaa4.Servlets"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp?useSSL=false");
        ds.setUser("emp");
        ds.setPassword("emp");
        ds.setMinPoolSize(2);
        ds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        ds.setMaxIdleTime(30000);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean mySessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        sf.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sf.setPackagesToScan("io.github");
        sf.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager myTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return htm;
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDao userDaoImpl() {
        return new UserDaoImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public DBService dBServiceImpl() {
        return new DBServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

serviceImpl snippet

```
@Service
public class DBServiceImpl implements DBService {

    //inject user DAO
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(MyUser user) {
        userDao.createUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<MyUser> getUserList() {
        return userDao.getusers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(int theId) {
        userDao.deleteUser(theId);
    }


}
```

main class

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        DBServiceImpl service = ctx.getBean(DBServiceImpl.class);

        MyUser user = new MyUser("alice", "and her passwd");
        System.out.println("this is the user:" + user);
        service.addUser(user);
        service.addUser(user);
        service.addUser(user);
        service.addUser(user);
        System.out.println("User added!");
        service.deleteUser(2);
        System.out.println("user number id = 2 deleted");
        List<MyUser> userList = service.getUserList();
        for (MyUser users : userList)
            System.out.println(users);
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

stacktrace with problem

```
  INFO: Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource[ identityToken -> 1hge1459o1fr6qmlst9469|42e99e4a, dataSourceName -> 1hge1459o1fr6qmlst9469|42e99e4a ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.github.aaa4.services.DBServiceImpl' available

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at io.github.aaa4.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

with annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) above the config class

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at io.github.aaa4.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.initBeanFactory(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setBeanFactory(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1647)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Could you double check that either the `aspectjtools` or `aspectjweaver` libs , exist in your application's classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an interface instead of an implementation

```
DBService service = ctx.getBean(DBService.class);
```

You have `@Transactional` annotations on your service methods. All `@Transactional` annotations should be scanned at startup time and the targeted methods should become transactional. To add transactional behavior Spring creates a proxy for your class. That's why you can't get your bean.

Comment: i've try it twice and get something like:
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'DBServiceImpl' is expected to be of type 'io.github.aaa4.services.DBServiceImpl' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29'

Comment: Have you used exactly the same code as I mentioned above?

Comment: and how to repair it ?
Do not use the interface? IMHO it's bad way.

Comment: Yes, the same snippet:
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        DBService service = ctx.getBean(DBService.class);
and then i've copy the error from terminal

Comment: No, you SHOULD use interface. Firstly, it is always a good practice to code to interfaces in general. Secondly, in a case of Spring, you can inject any implementation at runtime by the interface.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to check some guides about AOP and java config it.

Comment: Try to add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) to your config

Comment: try to add following dependencies

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.6</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: its works )
at previous step intellij sad that it import libs, but i think didn't do that, coz after manual maven pom checking it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think,you should make changes in this line `DBServiceImpl service = ctx.getBean(DBServiceImpl.class);` to `DBService service = ctx.getBean(DBService.class);`

for reference check spring doc [Using the @Bean annotation Spring DOC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-bean-annotation)

Comment: i've try it. look at answer below.

Answer (score 1):

"What's important to keep in mind is that, if the transactional bean is implementing an interface, by default the proxy will be a Java Dynamic Proxy. This means that only external method calls that come in through the proxy will be intercepted."

Refer https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring.

Following should make it work:

DBService service = ctx.getBean(DBService.class);